# Set due date 1 day after each multiple tasks are created

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, tasks

I want to know how to set the due date for task approval in SharePoint Designer workflow 2013. I have multiple task created for different level of approvals so the due date will be different for each task approval.

I tried to create a calculated column in task list with formula =Created+1 but the due date that the task is getting is 1/1/0001.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by creating a calculated column in the main list, not the task list, with formula =NOW()+1. This will get the current date and time. Today() will not work as it will get the current date but with default time at 12AM.

This will work since after every approval action, the item in the list is updated, and the NOW() value will change whenever the item is updated. So for the next approval task, the due date will be different from the the first task.

P/S: This will only work if there are no changes made to the item before the item is approved/rejected, or else the due date will change again